# Codename one map component does not let me input longitude and lattidude (+ permissions)

Tags: codenameone

1st question:

I am trying to use the map component from codename one Theme. However, every time i put longitude and lattitude, it resets to 0.0. How can i change that from inside the theme?

[image]

2nd question, if possible: How do i show permissions, in order to enable using your own location? It is automatic when I use the map component, but not for other components.
When i try to use web view with google map, it does not let me put my own location.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old GUI builder which is no longer maintained. I would recommend switching to the new GUI builder or using handcoding. Notice you might be better off starting a new project as the new GUI builder is **VERY** different.

`MapComponent` is also deprecated in favor of [native maps](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/mapping-natively.html) those are accessible from code and are far superior on the device... The [Uber clone app](https://codenameone.teachable.com/p/build-real-world-full-stack-mobile-apps-in-java) was built using native maps.

Location prompts are automatic when you use the `LocationManager` API. You can enable them in the simulator to see how it feels on the device. You can then use the [JavaScript interop](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-async-java-javascript-interop-api.html) to pass your location to embedded HTML.

Comment: I have gone too far using the Old GUI builder to switch to the new one.
I am using only the theme.res file to build my whole application. 
How do i check the source code of the entire theme.res file? The statemachinejava does not contain everything.

Comment: You need to override the specific callback. The old GUI builder provides buttons to let you override those. You should work with the native maps from code and not through the GUI builder.